# javascript geolocation not working unless I include alerts to display/delay the script

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, alert

I am having a problem with the GeoLocation API. Bascially I am trying to link to Google Maps (not embed) based on the user's location. If geolocation cannot be used, it will default to just showing the destination. The problem I am having is that unless I put alerts in the code, it will always default to the destination only.

Here is my code:

```
  function findPosition(position)
  {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    mapURL = "https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=50.795251,-1.107136&sensor=TRUE";

    alert("1 " +  mapURL); // Alert shows the URL correctly
  }

  if(navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findPosition);
  }

  alert("2 " +  mapURL); // Shows empty string as if findPosition() has not been called???
  alert("3 " +  mapURL); // Shows mapURL correctly

  if (mapURL == "")
  {
    // Set the default URL with only the destination
    mapURL = "https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=50.795251,-1.107136";
  }

  var link = "<a href=\"" + mapURL + "\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#000;\" target=\"_blank\">";

  document.write(link);
//-->
</script>
```

The comments next to the alerts are to demonstrate how the code works with them, however if the alerts are removed it always sets the destination only default URL.

I don't understand why alert 1 is showing the correct URL yet 2 is showing nothing, despite the fact that it should be processed after alert 1?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is async, so one solution is to pass to it a callback, as you did, which will be called when the location has been found (or when it threw an error).

You were seeing correct results using the `alert`s because you were giving time to the script to recognize the location.

One solution could be to move your code in the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback, which you called `findPosition`, like this:

```
function findPosition(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  mapURL = "https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=50.795251,-1.107136&sensor=TRUE";
  if (mapURL == "") {
    // Set the default URL with only the destination
    mapURL = "https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=50.795251,-1.107136";
  }

  var link = "<a href=\"" + mapURL + "\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#000;\" target=\"_blank\">";
  document.write(link);
}  

if(navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findPosition);
}
```